# SimpleMemberShip error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified, after 30 sec work

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I use ASP.NET MVC 4 with SimpleMemberShip.
I have 2 users and 2 roles in SimpleMemberShip's tables.
I can start the site in the local pc and all page will open successfully all time.

But if i start site in the hosting, all will work but only first time,
I can login. 
I can to open any page with [Authorize(Roles="Admins")] and without it
But after aproximatly 30 sec all page with [Authorize(Roles="Admins")] in
the controller don't work successfully. And I get SimpleMemberShip SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified.